# execute each line of output in bash

Tags: bash

I have a feeling there's already and answer to this but I wasn't able to find it.
How can I execute each line of output in bash as it comes out? 
For example, as my script runs, it generates,

```
command-1
command-2
command-3
etc.
```

I need some way to pipe them or something into something that will run them neatly. I've been experimenting with xargs but haven't found anything good to put on the receiving end.
I'd like to avoid doing something like dumping them into a separate script on the side if possible. (I also tried for loops, but they ended up breaking on words instead of lines.)

Comment: Why is your script generating commands? If you're doing it to inspect the output first or because you believe you have to add quotes, you should really reconsider.

Comment: @thatotherguy it generates commands because it's forming them from curl output: curl something|lotsofprocessing|listmaking|morejunk|magic commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ bash echosomecommands.sh | bash
```